# change subnav active link styling in squarespace

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, nav

A not-super-advanced coder here.I'm seeking to "simply" adjust the styling of an active link in a sub-navigation on a site.

Example page:
http://printergatherer.com/shop
Referencing the minty green sub-nav that has "ALL  ...  PRINTS" in it.

Right now, I have styling that effects the active link in ALL navigations on the site. Ideally I have one set of styles for the main nav, and one for this sub nav.

I've managed to add a mint green underline to the active link, which is great, but for whatever reason I just CANNOT get the link color itself to change to the same mint green.

This code gets the bottom-border, but not the correct link color:

```
#categoryNav ul li.active-link {
  color: #C6D4D0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C6D4D0;
}
```

Sorry if I'm being a noob, I am about to tear my hair out about something that seems so simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move the color off of the li and on to the anchor tag like so:

```
.active-link a {
 color: #c6d4d0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c6d4d0;
}
```

you can see a jsfiddle of it working here:https://jsfiddle.net/24k1zep4/3/

your CSS is really specific, if you can't change that you may have to actually use a more specific selector.

```
#categoryNav .category-nav-links .active-link a {
 color: #c6d4d0;    
}
```

should work if you can't change the specificity and need to override what is already there.

Comment: first fix didn't work, but 2nd did. I'm not in developer mode in Squarespace, but I bet if I was the first fix could've worked out. Thank you so much!